# Flex-box Row Span

Tags: html, css, flexbox, row

I've seen some solutions for this using flex-direction: column but that was for the entire flex container. I already have a container with a row direction and wanted to know if I could make a two row div without changing the whole layout. Here's my current situation.

[image: calculator]

I'd like to combine the blank div with the div with the equal sign. Here's my code as well. Thanks a lot!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="headline">
        JSCalc
    </div>
    <div class="display">
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="ac all-rows row1 clear">AC</div>
        <div class="ce all-rows row1 clear">CE</div>
        <div class="divide all-rows row1">&divide;</div>
        <div class="multiply all-rows row1">&times;</div>

        <div class="seven all-rows">7</div>
        <div class="eight all-rows">8</div>
        <div class="nine all-rows">9</div>
        <div class="subtract all-rows">-</div>

        <div class="four all-rows">4</div>
        <div class="five all-rows">5</div>
        <div class="six all-rows">6</div>
        <div class="addition all-rows">+</div>

        <div class="three all-rows">3</div>
        <div class="two all-rows">2</div>
        <div class="one all-rows">1</div>
        <div class="all-rows">
        </div>


        <div class="zero all-rows">0</div>
        <div class="decimal all-rows">.</div>
        <div class="all-rows">=</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
html {
background-color: #333;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 3%;
}

.headline {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.display {
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #DFE2DB;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #c6cbbf;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.button-container {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-rows {
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.row1 {
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.clear {
    background-color: #e19ba2;
}

.zero {
    width: 47%;
}

.decimal {
    flex-grow: 0;
    width: 22%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, slipped my mind! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a pseudo and bridge the two, visually.

Add these 2 rules (and the `equal` class to the markup)

```
.equal {
    position: relative;
}
.equal::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 90%;            /* start 10% below the top to cover the rounded border */
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
}
```

*Note, when you add the events, you need to add the "equal" event to both the `equal` button and the one above it.*

Stack snippet

```css
html {
background-color: #333;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 3%;
}

.headline {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.display {
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #DFE2DB;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #c6cbbf;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.button-container {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-rows {
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.row1 {
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.clear {
    background-color: #e19ba2;
}

.zero {
    width: 47%;
}

.decimal {
    flex-grow: 0;
    width: 22%;
}

.equal {
    position: relative;
}
.equal::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 90%;            /* start 10% below the top to cover the rounded border */
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="headline">
        JSCalc
    </div>
    <div class="display">
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="ac all-rows row1 clear">AC</div>
        <div class="ce all-rows row1 clear">CE</div>
        <div class="divide all-rows row1">&divide;</div>
        <div class="multiply all-rows row1">&times;</div>

        <div class="seven all-rows">7</div>
        <div class="eight all-rows">8</div>
        <div class="nine all-rows">9</div>
        <div class="subtract all-rows">-</div>

        <div class="four all-rows">4</div>
        <div class="five all-rows">5</div>
        <div class="six all-rows">6</div>
        <div class="addition all-rows">+</div>

        <div class="three all-rows">3</div>
        <div class="two all-rows">2</div>
        <div class="one all-rows">1</div>
        <div class="all-rows"></div>

        <div class="zero all-rows">0</div>
        <div class="decimal all-rows">.</div>
        <div class="all-rows equal">=</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

Another way is to wrap the `3`/`2`/`1`/`0`/`.`/ and the /`=`/ into 2 groups, make those wrappers flex row containers and then adjust their width's/margin's to match the rest of the buttons.